# Python - is plt.text.remover() possible?

Tags: python, text, plot

I plot the values of an array on a figure in Python, for that I use the following code.

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        plt.text(i,j,myArray[j][i],fontsize=11)
```

I want to do something similar, so I can remove the current values to write new ones. 
I have been searching for a while, but couldn't find an answer. How could this be achieved?

Comment: If you are just going to replace some text with another text you may also consider just changing the contents of the exiting text objects with [`set_text()`](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_text)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a collection with texts and then remove them

```
texts = []
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        text =  plt.text(i, j, myArray[j][i], fontsize=11)
        texts.append(text)

for i in range(len(texts)):
    texts[i].remove()
texts = []
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't remove the plotted text from the figure. This best would be 'if possible' to add a button e.g. reset to the figure, that clears the text at once.

Comment: You should draw the plot again to see changes, add  `fig.canvas.draw()`.